# Hover background of select - Default chrome how to change to other

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, css

[image]

Could you please let me know how to remove the background color of
   hover and change it into the some other color.

```css
.drp-policydetails {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div className="form-group">
  <select className="form-control drp-policydetails">
    <option hidden>-- Select One --</option>
    <option>123456789</option>
    <option>789232323</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and we'll help you from there.

Answer (score -1):

In general, you can't. This element is rendered by the OS, not HTML. It cannot be styled via CSS. There are replacement plug-ins that look like a  but are actually composed of regular HTML elements that CAN be styled.

Taken from: [How to style the option of a html "select"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)

---

Edit: (can be something to work with..)
You can create custom select like here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp
The idea is hide the original select element and style it custom.